# Caesar Cipher Frequency Analysis in Java

Tags: java, caesar-cipher, frequency-analysis

Caesar Cipher using Frequency Analysis** in Java: this is my code for the decode part:

```
public static String decode (String code){
    int key=0;
    final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
    int[] freqs = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];
    for (int l=0;l<freqs.length;l++){ 
        freqs[l]=0;
    }
    for (int k=0;k<code.length();k++){
        if (code.charAt(k)>='a' && code.charAt(k)<='z'){
            freqs[code.charAt(k)-'a']++;
        }
    }
    int biggest = 0;
    for (int t=0;t<freqs.length;t++){
        if (freqs[t]>biggest){
            biggest= t;
        }
    }
    if (biggest<4){
        key = (biggest + 26 - ('e'+'a'));

    }
    else{
        key = biggest + 'a' - 'e';
    }
    return (decode(code,key));
}
```

I cannot use maps, imports, lists, or add a key, I do know that the most freq letter is E but I do not know how to implement it in a different function. I would appreciate a more elegant solution, thank you. ** Frequency Analysis

Comment: A more elegant solution would use all the Java objects you have it's an oriented object language so a better solution would use it

Comment: Letter frequencies: ETAOINSHRDLU... though [space] is more frequent than E.

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure what your definition of "elegant" is, but your solution looks fine in general.

A few comments:

1. You don't actually have to manually initialise your array to 0 at the start since Java will do that for you
2. Looking for the letter with the highest frequency can be done while you are counting the characters

For example, the `for` loop can become:

```
int highestFreq = 0;
int highestFreqIdx = -1;
for (int k=0; k < code.length(); k++) {
    if (code.charAt(k) >= 'a' && code.charAt(k) <= 'z') {
        int count = freqs[code.charAt(k)-'a']++;

        if (count > highestFreq) {
          highestFreq = count;
          highestFreqIdx = k;
        }
    }
}
```

3. Calculating the key can be simplified

If I am not wrong, your key is the number of positions that the letter with the highest frequency is away from 'e'. In this case, you can simply do this:

```
key = biggest - ('e' - 'a');
```

So your code becomes:

```
public static String decode (String code){
    int key = 0;
    final int ALPHABET_SIZE = 26;
    int[] freqs = new int[ALPHABET_SIZE];

    int highestFreq = 0;
    int highestFreqIdx = -1;
    for (int k=0; k < code.length(); k++) {
        if (code.charAt(k) >= 'a' && code.charAt(k) <= 'z') {
            int count = freqs[code.charAt(k)-'a']++;

            if (count > highestFreq) {
              highestFreq = count;
              highestFreqIdx = k;
            }
        }
    }

    key = highestFreqIdx - ('e' - 'a'); // Can also directly use 4 instead of 'e' - 'a'

    return (decode(code, key));
}
```

That said, your code will only work for messages that really have the letter 'e' as the most common letter...

P/S Such code review questions may be better off in [this Stack Exchange site for code reviews instead](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)